# simple python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a feeling that there is a simple answer to this question, but I am having trouble getting the answer without having to write many many lines of code.  I was hoping someone may give me something that will make my life easier in regards to list comprehensions in python.

What I have is this:

```
highest_peak = sorted([(self.Y[x]-self.background_model[x]) for x in peaks_index_list])[0]
```

How do I obtain the index (x) of the highest_peak from the peaks_index_list where this occurs?

```
index_of_highest_peak = sorted(???)[0]
index_of_second_highest_peak = sorted(???)[1]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be sorting a list of tuples of the form (value,index) --

```
info = sorted((self.Y[x]-self.background_model[x],x) for x in peaks_index_list)
```

Now your index of the highest peak is:

```
info[-1][1]
```

Or you can unpack it a little more nicely:

```
highest_peak_value,highest_peak_index = info[-1]
```

(highest peak is last in the sorted list since we didn't specify `reverse=True`)

The second highest peak index is:

```
info[-2][1]
```

and so on.

Comment: Wonderful!  I always forget about tuples and the idea of adding two variables (value, index) to iterate over in loops (forgot what that's called). This is a good amount of information and extremely useful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you use numpy you can

```
import numpy as np
highest_peak = np.asarray(highest_peak)

max_index = highest_peak.argmax()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is a very understandable and concise code piece.  I think [mgilson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/748858/mgilson) has a more versatile form for arriving to get the second and 3rd ranked items, but this is still very useful.

Answer (score 3):

I take it the peak height is `self.Y[i] - self.background_model[i]` for a peak index `i`? If all you want is the index of the highest peak:

```
max(peaks_index_list, key=lambda i: self.Y[i] - self.background_model[i])
```

Likewise, if you really want the sorted list, use the above key [to sort `peaks_index_list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: this is true, but it won't give OP the second largest -- Although you could accomplish that by using `sorted` instead of `max` I suppose.

Comment: @mgilson That's what I had in mind with the second part of my answer. Starting out with a list of indices is a little cumbersome, but based on OP's literal question it wasn't obvious he needed a list of peak heights themselves.

Answer (score 2):

(note: edited based on comments)

Add the index to the objects being sorted:

```
highest_peak, index = sorted([(self.Y[x]-self.background_model[x], x)
    for x in peaks_index_list])[0]
```

(originally I suggested using enumerate(), which is great when you want the index of the elements you are enumerating. In this case, the peaks_index_list is already the index the poster was after.)

```
highest_peak, index = sorted([(self.Y[x]-self.background_model[x], i)
    for i, x in enumerate(peaks_index_list]))[0]
```

Comment: OP wants the index `x`, not index `i` (If I understand corectly)

Comment: Yes, I wanted the `x` value, however this is still useful as it calls attention to enumerate() in general, which may be helpful to anyone who Google's an issue similar to this. Thanks, tdelaney.

Comment: oops, I changed it while you were typing! I think I'll add the old one back.